# slowing down a webscrape using python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a site and the problem I am running into is the page takes time to load.  So by the time my scraping is done I may get only five items when there may be 25.  Is there a way to slow down python.  I am using beautifulSoup
Here is the code I am using

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

theurl="http://agscompany.com/product-category/fittings/tube-nuts/316-tube/"
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")

for pn in soup.find_all('div',{"class":"shop-item-text"}):
    pn2 = pn.text
    print(pn2)
```

Thank you

Comment: Please post your code...

Comment: It's more likely that the webpage uses javascript to load more items as the user scrolls.

Comment: code added - sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the results can be accessed from theses pages :

http://agscompany.com/product-category/fittings/tube-nuts/316-tube/page/
http://agscompany.com/product-category/fittings/tube-nuts/316-tube/page/2/
...

So you can access them with a loop on the page number :

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

theurl="http://agscompany.com/product-category/fittings/tube-nuts/316-tube/"
for i in range(1,5):
  thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl + '/page/' + str(i) + '/')
  soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")

  for pn in soup.find_all('div',{"class":"shop-item-text"}):
      pn2 = pn.text
      print(pn2)
```

Answer (score 1):

More generic version of @Kenavoz's answer.

This approach doesn't care about how many pages there are.

Also, I would go for `requests` rather than `urllib`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_pattern = 'http://agscompany.com/product-category/fittings/tube-nuts/316-tube/page/{index}/'
status_code = 200    
url_index = 1

while status_code == 200:
    url = url_pattern.format(index=url_index)
    response = requests.get(url)

    status_code = response.status_code
    url_index += 1

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    page_items = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'shop-item-text'})

    for page_item in page_items:
        print(page_item.text)
```